# From JSON Response Use List of Lists to Display Averages on Multiple Columns Using Python

Tags: python, json, list, for-loop

If I have a list of lists that I obtain from an API response that I want to find the averages of, and I am looking at two or more different responses (say I look at two different players in a baseball game). I want to use pandas dataframe to display each player's averages, but I don't want it to reprint their averages just below the other as seen below.

Let's say I have an API address that I only need to change the variable players of in order to get the next player's stats.

> 'stats.mlb.com/mlb/2014-15/gamelog/'+player+'&SeasonType=Regular+Season'

So if I want to look at multiple players, I create a for loop that iterates through a list of players I'm interested in:

Below is the response I get when I print the df.mean() of the response I get from a list of multiple players:

P - Player ID

```
P   4100
H   55
R   27
ER  24
HR  5 
BB  19

P   4200
H   44
R   30
ER  24
HR  8 
BB  22
.
.
.
```

Currently I have a for-loop that iterates through each player ID, assigning the new ID to the end of the API address, then I obtain the response and create a dataframe in which I am interested in obtaining the mean from.

players = ['4100','4200','4300']
for player in players:

> URL_PATTERN1='stats.mlb.com/201415/gamelog/'+player+'&SeasonType=Regular+Season'

response_stats = requests.get(URL_PATTERN1)
mlb_data = data_mlb['resultSets'][0]['rowSet'] #mlb_data is now a list of lists of mlb stats

Each time I go to a new player's ID, it creates a new dataframe. I would like it to output their averaged stats using pandas as so below:

```
P   4100   4200   4300   ...
H   55     44     40     ...
R   27     30     25     ...
ER  24     24     28     ...
HR  5      8      9      ...
BB  19     22     20     ...
```

I think I have to take the following approach:

1. Given that I have a list of lists of each game that a player has played in; I use df.mean() to obtain that average
2. Since I have more than one player I should somehow store those averages, created by the dataframe in another list that looks like below
   [[4100,55,27,24,5,19][4200,44,30,24,8,22],[...]]

Using this list of list of averages then create another dataframe of all the players that I have stored averages of?

I'm not sure how I might do that. Or obtain the averages as easy it is to print df.mean()

The game log stats of the API response look like below:

```
[["0021401229",12425489,"DEN","Denver",4200,"Joe Schmoe",4.25,1.6,1,7,8,39,0,0,20,0,7,9,0.778,0,4,0.000,0.538],["0021401230",12425490,"MIL","Milwaukee",4200,"Joe Schmoe",4.25,1.6,1,7,8,39,0,0,20,0,7,9,0.778,0,4,0.000,0.538],...]
```

Then the program goes to the next player's API response:

```
[["0021401229",12425489,"DEN","Denver",4300,"Choe Schmoe",4.25,1.6,1,7,8,39,0,0,20,0,7,9,0.778,0,4,0.000,0.538],["0021401230",12425490,"MIL","Milwaukee",4200,"Joe Schmoe",4.25,1.6,1,7,8,39,0,0,20,0,7,9,0.778,0,4,0.000,0.538],...]
```

and so forth... I would like it all to print out as shown above or take averages line by line.